# Using functions.php to override functions on other folders

Tags: wordpress

Good mourning everyone  :)

I'm trying to understand something here about child themes:

I have a function() in inc/sor.php (parent theme).
My understanding is that I **must** create a folder (inc) in child theme then create the sor.php file, from here I can override the function().

But that wasn't working!! I only managed to make it work when I moved the changes to functions.php file of child theme!!

So is it always this way? I mean all functions should be overritten in the functions.php???

Please clarify this matter.

Thank you in advance for you assistance.

Comment: Your parent theme includes this `inc/sor.php` somewhere. Your child theme doesn't, that's why just creating and modifying it within child theme directory wouldn't work. You can either do it within `functions.php` of child theme as you did or include `inc/sor.php` within child theme folder inside child theme's `function.php` and the override your functions there.

Comment: Aha so that's why.. Thanks this helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The comment of [@Igor Yavych](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35616856/using-functions-php-to-override-functions-on-other-folders#comment-58919594) is right. In addition:

The child's functions.php is loaded right **before** parent's. Now your function isn't being loaded at all, but if the function `foo()` of your parent theme isn't wrapped by `if (function_exists('foo'))` you will have an error, because the code will have two functions with the same name.

Comment: No it's not wrapped with if conditional, I just used remove_action to stop the function in parent theme from loading then added the new modified function.

Comment: Thanks for commenting.